# Convergence of convolution with an even summability kernel

Tags: convergence-divergence, convolution

Suppose that $f(\theta) : [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a monotone increasing real valued function and $\{k_n\}$ is an [even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even_functions) [summability kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summability_kernel).

I want to show that $f \star k_n$ converges pointwise. My intuition is that the limit of this pointwise convergence is $f$, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: if $h_n \to \delta$, $f \ast h_n \to f$ pointwise only if $f$ is continuous, and "even summability kernel" doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: @user1952009: "even" as in each $K_n$ is an even function, $K_n(-x) = K_n(x)$ and I've linked to a description of summability kernels.

Comment: so the answer is : the convergence is pointwise only at the points where $f$ is continuous.